# Converting Strings to Integer and get the persentage of two number

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is to make a progress bar for donation. My html structure is:

```
<div class="hgoal" style="text-align: center;">My goal is to raise $<span id="mygoal">9,999.00</span></div>
<div class="donation-total">Total Donation<span id="total-donation">1,000.00</span></div>
```

my javascript so far is to get the innerHTML value of mygoal and total-donation.

```
var mygoal = document.getElementById("mygoal").innerHTML;
var totalgoal = document.getElementById("total-donation").innerHTML;
```

and I'm getting this as a result:

```
mygoal = "9,999.00";
total-donation = "1,000.00";
```

I believe this is a string and not an integer, and using `parseInt()` only give me the first digit number.

Can anyone give me an idea how can I make this into an integer that can use for computation? example:

```
mygoal + total-donation = 10,999.00
```

And also, any idea how can i get the percentage of this two varible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.replace(/,/g,'')` to replace commas, then you get the magic of type coercion to convert your string to a number during calculation...

```
var mygoal = document.getElementById("mygoal").innerHTML.replace(/,/g,'');
var totalgoal = document.getElementById("total-donation").innerHTML.replace(/,/g,'');
```

If you use `+` on strings, they will be appended to each other, but other mathematical operators (`*/-` etc...) will first coerce the strings into numbers. To force coercion, you can multiply by 1, or perhaps use `Number("123123.123")`...

```
Number(mygoal) + Number(totalgoal); // using addition, so coerce strings to numbers
(mygoal / total_donation) * 100; // does not need coercion
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `parseFloat()`, not `parseInt()` ...
More, you have to remove the commas from the string, since `parseFloat()` does not undertsand number formatting characters (like comma). So, for example:

```
mygoal = mygoal.replace(/,/g, '');
total_donation = total_donation.replace(/,/g, '');
```

To get the percentage of two numbers, use:

```
(mygoal / total_donation) * 100;
```

Note that in JavaScript you can't use 'minus' char (`-`) in variables names.
You could use for example 'underscore' char (`_`), or [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), wich is the recommended style for variables in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is, that your numbers include colons. The parseFloat() call will work, once you replace these colons. You may use the following code to do so:

```
// define regexp to replace colons
var replaceColons = new RegExp(',', 'g');

// apply regex
num = num.replace(replaceColons, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

`mygoal=parseInt(mygoal.replace(/,/gi,""))` will give you `mygoal=9999`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert those Indian (maybe) numbers to valid Javascript numbers for the sum, then convert the output back to the initial format using [`Number.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

```js
var mygoal = "9,999.00";
var total_donation = "1,000.00";
var total = Number((Number(mygoal.replace(/,/g, '')) + Number(total_donation.replace(/,/g, ''))).toFixed(2));
var finalResult = total.toLocaleString('en-IN',{minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
alert(finalResult);
```

Comment: Apart from being hard to understand for beginners, this solution won't work for numbers > 10^6.

Comment: @Dodekeract I've updated my answer. I'm glad to receive more feedbacks.